# What is meant by a webmodule?

Tags: web-applications, terminology

At my job, people sometimes speak about a 'webmodule'. But when I search for this term on the internet, I don't get any relevant results for an definition. (either at google, or at the [w3c](https://www.w3.org/)
)

What do people mean when they talk about webmodules?

Comment: Since I am getting downvotes on this question, can you please tell me how this question can be improved? Judging from other questions on this site, asking for definitions is within scope.

Comment: Since that's not a standard term, why don't you ask your colleagues how exactly they define a _webmodule_? It's unlikel that someone here can give you a concise definition beyond plain speculation.

Comment: The term “web module” may have a specific meaning in certain technology stacks, e.g. JavaScript modules or JavaEE web modules. But it's likely to be a term specific to your workplace.

Comment: Ah, so webmodule is not a standard term. That is what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by πάντα ῥεῖ:

> 'webmodule' is not a standard term. You will need to ask your
> colleagues for their definition. It is likely a term specific to your workplace.